# How to prevent scrolling on table view from registering taps to seg control on iOS 7?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, scroll, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a tableview with a UISegmentedControl as a subview on each row (cell).  Before iOS 7 I could scroll up and down freely without any finger contact being interpreted as a tap on a segment.  Now, *only* on iOS7, I cannot scroll without unwanted firing of setSelectedSegmetIndex.  If the user is not paying attention they unknowingly change settings when simply intending to scroll.  Any way to prevent this?  I am using Xcode 5 targeting iOS 6 builds, and bc of our customer base need to be able to do this, since some will not have upgraded. If I target iOS 7 things work as usual, it only seems to be when iOS 6 targeted builds are run on a device upgraded to iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, and it seems clear that Apple is not going to do anything to address it. In iOS 7 UIButton and UISegmentedControl objects placed on UITableViewCell objects will interpret user touches intended as swipes as taps (selections)  This was not the case with iOS 6.  Here's the vague, non-commital reply I received back from the Apple engineer:  "After some investigation there indeed appears to be several changes within iOS 7 in how controls within UITableViewCells interact with gesture recognizers.  For iOS 7 the table view is making its best attempts to mediate or allow controls like sliders and segmented controls to have a higher propiority over gesture/touch events.  So this behavioral change doesn't appear to be customizeable, at least not allowing to revert back to the older behavior in iOS 6."  My intention is not to besmirch Apple's reputation here.  The previous times I've worked with their engineers they made determined efforts to figure out if their code was the cause, and admitted it clearly if so, offering help for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue with Deployment target 6.0 and 7.0 SDK. But I didn't face the issue.

If you want to manually manage the firing of setSelectedSegmentIndex,

you can set the property momentary to YES on your segmented control.

Comment: I just finished a very simple app that reproduces it. iOS 6 app on iOS 7 is the combination that doesn't work right.  iOS 6 app on iOS 6 device, or iOS 7 app on iOS 7 device works normally.

Comment: ManicMonkOnMac, unfortunately I cannot "manually manage" things using the momentary property because I cannot detect the difference between user touches intended for scrolling and user touches intended for selections on the segmented control.

Comment: Apple Developer Technical Support has responded quickly to my submission of this as an issue.  I will post updates here when it makes sense to do so. Btw, UIButton objects placed in sequence on a UITableViewCell exhibit the same exact behavior.

Comment: This also seems to apply to all scroll views. Thanks for looking into it, would definitely appreciate any updates you can give.